# What is the best way to make UI for an Isometric game in java

Tags: java, gui

What do you think is the best way to make UI for an isometric game.. I dont have much experience in UI so im not sure where to start.

I need something the mouse can interact with and that works good and fast. I already created a world that is isometric you can move and the world scrolls and stuff but i would like to start with UI and im not sure what i should do.

I would like to have maybe a display that displays an image that i give it, that is part invisible, that it is on top of the main game panel and that i route an area to be clicked on it by a mouse. i would like some help with the code behind because I'm not sure how to get the specific area. By the way do you think this would be a good way?

Thanks for the help..

Comment: anyone? i really need help.

Comment: If you really need help (and need it "now"), the best way is to help yourself. Instead of waiting for answers to show up here, do some research. You haven't shown any research effort here.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use a library designed to provide GUI functionality. This will be specific to how you want to use it, and what you're using already. Here are some common ones:

- [Nifty Gui](http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/)
- [Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/)
- [TWL](http://twl.l33tlabs.org/)
- [javootoo](http://www.javootoo.com/)
- [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)
- [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/)
- [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29)
- And many more, just a Google search away!